# Make inline block align at top instead of bottom

Tags: html, css, block, inline

Best way for me to explain this problem is with the following images.

This:
[image]

Needs to appear like this:
[image]

I believe the only code affecting these two container objects (working results and result viewer) is the following css snippet.

```
.ItemCollection {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;
}
```

Is this a very simple css change to be made or do I need to add some more in depth coding to make this happen?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? OR a link to the web site?

Comment: @Alek  Let me see. Give me just a minute!

Comment: doesn't `vertical-align: top` help?

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn BEAUTIFUL! Easiest answer I've ever got on here! Make and actual answer and it's yours! :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Div boxes not aligning properly using inline-block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662476/div-boxes-not-aligning-properly-using-inline-block)

Comment: I used the title of your post to perform a google search. The first search result answered your question. Next time you have a question, please do some basic research first. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you need to add `vertical-align : top` to both divs

```
.ItemCollection {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```